# how to do minus in string sql

Tags: sql

I've the column on the table like FurnaceRunno (GM15-737). So, I want to do minus one in FurnaceRunno.

the output should come like this:(minus one value, fixed for every furnacerunno)

```
FurnaceRunno  :GM15-737      
output        :GM15-736
```

Comment: hint.. replace "-" with 0 then exclude "GM" then -1 then append "GM" back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SUBSTRING(FurnaceRunno, 0, charindex('-', FurnaceRunno, 1)) + '-' 
+ CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(FurnaceRunno, charindex('-', FurnaceRunno, 1) + 1, len(FurnaceRunno))) - 1)
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1A' to data type int.

Comment: So you have non-numeric data after `-` as well?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
declare @mytext varchar(10) = 'GM15-736'
declare @prefix varchar(2) = left(@mytext,2)

select @prefix + cast( replace(replace(@mytext,'-','0'),@prefix,'') + 1 as varchar(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these queries --

```
-- Query 1:
DECLARE @Result INT
SET @Result = CAST(RIGHT('GM15-737', 3) AS INT) - 1
SELECT REPLACE('GM15-737', SUBSTRING('GM15-737', 6, 3), CAST(@Result AS 
VARCHAR)) 

-- Query 2:
DECLARE @Result1 INT, @OutputString VARCHAR(255)

SET @Result1 = CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE('GM15-737', '-', ''), 3, 5) AS INT) - 1
SET @OutputString = CONCAT('GM', CAST(@Result1 AS VARCHAR(255)))
SET @OutputString = STUFF(CAST(@OutputString AS VARCHAR(255)), 5, 0, '-')
PRINT @OutputString
```

Don't forget to mark it as an answer please if it helps you solve your answer. :)